# how to hot update a restful bundle to karaf when dev

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf, pax-web

everyone, I followed the karaf guide, the bundle:watch command and the remote debug is ok, but when I issue a mvn clean install command in a web project with restful service, karaf failed to update the bundle, here is the error:

```
2016-12-20 15:02:32,054 | ERROR | (WebApplication:265) - Registration skipped for [ServletWebElement{mapping=DefaultServletMapping{httpContextId=opencast.httpcontext,urlPatterns=null,initParams={},servlet=StaticResource [alias=/engage/ui, classpath=/ui, welcome file=index.html], alias=/engage/ui, servletNamenull}}] due to error during registration
```

so the question is how to hot update a restful web bundle when dev?

Comment: a bit more information is needed, what kind of bundle is it. How do you register your service? Is it a WAB, do you just register servlets via the HttpService, do you register your servlet as Service so the whiteboard-extender picks it up?

Comment: the bundle is a opencast project bundle.

Comment: here is the maven-plugin config:   `
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Build-Number>${buildNumber}</Build-Number>
            <Import-Package> org.opencastproject.rest;version=${project.version}</Import-Package>
            <Private-Package>ui.*</Private-Package>
            <Http-Alias>/engage/ui</Http-Alias>
            <Http-Classpath>/ui</Http-Classpath>
            <Http-Welcome>index.html</Http-Welcome>
          </instructions>`

Comment: please edit your question, with code, cause that is not really readable :)

Comment: sorry, this is the first time i add comment. i have resovled the problem,thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have resovled the problem.here is the answer link to reference:[opencast dev mail list](https://groups.google.com/a/opencast.org/forum/#!topic/dev/gxBUfHQCfFI)